# Select top 4 with order by, but only if actually required?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have part of a stored proc that is called thousands and thousands of times and as a result takes up the bulk of the whole thing. Having run it through execution plan it looks like the TOP 4 and Order By part is taking up a lot of that. The order by uses a function that although streamlined, will still be being used a fair bit.

This is an odd situation in that for 99.5% of the data there will be 4 or less results returned anyway, it's only for the 0.5% of times that we need the TOP 4. This is a requirement of the data algorithm so eliminating the TOP 4 entirely is not an option.

So lets say my syntax is

```
SELECT SomeField * SomeOtherField as MainField, SomeOtherField
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 4
        SomeField, 1/dbo.[Myfunction](Param1, Param2, 34892) as SomeOtherField
    FROM #MytempTable
    WHERE 
        Param1 > @NextMargin1 AND Param1 < @NextMargin1End
        AND Param2 > @NextMargin2 AND Param2 < @NextMargin2End
    ORDER BY dbo.[MyFunction](Param1, Param2, 34892)
) d
```

Is there a way I can tell SQL server to do the order by if and only if there are more than 4 results returned after the where takes place? I don't need the order otherwise. Perhaps a table variable and count of the table in an if?

--- Update based on Davids Answer to try to work out why it was slower:

I did a check and can confirm that 96.5% of times there are 4 or less results so it's not a case of more data than expected.

Here is the execution plan for the insert into the @FunctionResults
[image: Execution Plan 1]

And the breakdowns of the Insert and spool:
[image: Breakdowns]

And then the execution plan for the selection of the top4 and orderby:
[image: Execution Plan2]

Please let me know if any further information or breakdowns are required, the size of #Mytemptable could typically be 28000 rows and it has index

```
CREATE INDEX MyIndex on #MyTempTable (Param1, Param2) INCLUDE ([SomeField])
```

Comment: . . I find it hard to believe that sorting four or fewer result rows would result in the performance problem.  I suspect that the overall query is the issue, particularly the inequalities in the `where` clause (which make using indexes difficult) and the call to `dbo.MyFunction()`.

Comment: The sorting uses dbo.Myfunction, removing the orderby removes about 80% of the function calls, so it's not the sorting itself but the sortings reliance on the function. If we can minimise the sorting to be only in the 0.5% of cases requiring I will get wins on that side of things

Comment: Try using `order by SomeOtherField desc`, assuming the values are positive.  This might save the extra calls when sorting.

Comment: Try converting the function to a table valued function and join to it using the APPLY operator. Currently it is effectively the same as using a cursor!

Comment: Gordon - I got a 25% saving with your suggestion. Steve - Please could you add an answer with an example of how the apply syntax would work in this instance, assuming the table valued function is called MyTableFunction?

Comment: You can do two selects - only in case if first one returns more than 4 rows - using function call only on second.

Comment: @Arvo happy to also try that - I would guess the case would be based on the count of the select without the top 4 and orderby, could you show the SQL for this please?

Comment: select .... if @@rowcount > 4 select top 4 ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer has been updated based on continued feedback from the question asker. The original suggestion was to attempt to use a table variable to store pre-calculations and select the top 4 from the results. However, in practice it appears that the optimizer was over-estimating the number of rows and choosing a bad execution plan.

In addition to the previous recommendations, I would also recommend updating statistics periodically after any change to this process to provide the query optimizer with updated information to make more informed decisions.

As this is a performance tuning process without direct access to the source environment, this answer is expected to change based on user feedback. Per the recommendation of @SteveFord above, the sample query below reflects the use of a CROSS APPLY to attempt to avoid multiple unnecessary function calls.

```
SELECT TOP 4
    M.SomeField,
    M.SomeField * 1/F.FunctionResults [SomeOtherField]
FROM #MytempTable M
CROSS APPLY (SELECT dbo.Myfunction(M.Param1, M.Param2, 34892)) F(FunctionResults)
ORDER BY F.FunctionResults
```

Comment: Surprisingly this has ground the stored procedure to a halt, theres something about this method that sql server isn't liking

Comment: I think perhaps it's the extra insert? For a typical 2 minute runtime the above code would be hit say 200000 times

Comment: @Knightsy Can you show us query execution plans? I wouldn't expect the insert into a table variable, which usually works as an in memory object, to offer slower performance. Is it possible that more data is being returned than expected?

Comment: Updated above, let me know if more info is required to get the performance going. 96.5% of times it is 4 or less, and 100% of the time 8 or less.